# Django model save the form but does not show me

Tags: python, html, django, web, backend

Hi I have created a address model  and link that model to the forms and created the view. but that form does save any data but that data does not show to me. Although it show me that data in the terminal .
this is my address model:

```html
from django.db import models
from billing.models import BillingProfile
# Create your models here.
ADDRESS_TYPES = (
    ('billing' , 'Billing'),
    ('shipping' , 'Shipping'),
)


class Address(models.Model):
    billing_profile     = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    addresss_type        = models.CharField(max_length=120 , choices=ADDRESS_TYPES)
    address_line_1      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_line_2      = models.CharField(max_length=120 , null=True , blank= True)
    city                = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    country             = models.CharField(max_length=120 ,default='Pakistan')
    postal_code         = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.billing_profile)
```

since I connect address model with billingprofile so the billing model is:

```html
class BillingProfile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User ,null=True , blank=True , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email       = models.EmailField()
    active      =models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    time_stamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = BillingProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and I call my address model into form
**forms.py/address**

```html
from django import forms
from .models import Address

class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['address_line_1','address_line_2','city','country','postal_code']
```

and my address/views.py is:

```html
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url
# Create your views here.
from billing.models import BillingProfile
from .forms import AddressForm

def checkout_address_create_view(request):
    form = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    next_ = request.GET.get('next')
    next_post = request.POST.get('next')
    redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None
    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        billing_profile ,  billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if billing_profile is not None:
            instance.billing_profile = billing_profile
            instance.address_type = request.POST.get('address_type','shipping')
            instance.save()
        else:
            print("Error Here")
            return redirect("cart:checkout")

        if is_safe_url(redirect_path , request.get_host()):
            return redirect(redirect_path)
        else:
            return redirect("cart:checkout")
    return redirect("cart:checkout")
```

and my address/form.html is:

now my form.html is:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{% if action_url%}{{ action_url }} {% else %}{% url 'login' %}{% endif %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
    {% if next_url %}
       <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next_url }}"/>
    {% endif %}

    {% if address_type %}
        <input type="hidden" name="address_type" value="{{ address_type }}"/>
      {% endif %}
                {{form.as_p}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
              </form>
```

and this form is shown on cart home so the cart view is:

```html
def checkout_home(request):
    cart_obj , cart_created = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    order_obj = None
    if  cart_created or cart_obj.products.count() ==0:
        return redirect("cart:home")
    login_form = LoginForm()
    guest_form = GuestForm()
    address_form =AddressForm()
    billing_address_form = AddressForm()

    billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
    if billing_profile is not None:
        order_obj , order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_profile , cart_obj)


    context= {
        "object" : order_obj,
        "billing_profile" : billing_profile,
        "login_form" : login_form,
        "guest_form" :guest_form,
        "address_form" :address_form,
        "billing_address_form" : billing_address_form,

    }

    return render(request , "carts/checkout.html" , context)
```

and my checkout html is:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}


{{object.order_id}} -- {{object.cart}}

{% if not billing_profile %}
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <p class="lead">Login</p>
        {% include 'accounts/snippets/form.html' with form=login_form next_url=request.build_absolute_uri %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <p class="lead">Continue as guest</p>

        {% url "guest_register" as guest_register_url %}
        {% include 'accounts/snippets/form.html' with form=guest_form next_url=request.build_absolute_uri action_url=guest_register_url %}
    </div>
    </div>
{% else %}

         {% if not object.shipping_address %}
                <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto col-10">
                             <p class="lead">Shipping Address</p>
                                {% url "checkout_address_create" as checkout_address_create %}
                                {% include 'addresses/form.html' with form=address_form next_url=request.build_absolute_uri action_url=checkout_address_create address_type='shipping' %}
                          </div>
                </div>
         {% elif not object.billing_address%}
            <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto col-10">
                             <p class="lead">Billing Address</p>
                                {% url "checkout_address_create" as checkout_address_create %}
                                {% include 'addresses/form.html' with form=address_form next_url=request.build_absolute_uri action_url=checkout_address_create address_type='billing' %}
                          </div>
            </div>

         {% else %}

                <h1>Finalize Checkout</h1>
            <p>Cart_total:{{object.cart.total}}</p>
            <p>Shipping Total:{{object.shipping_total}}</p>
            <p>Order Total:{{object.total}}</p>
            <button>Checkout</button>
         {% endif %}

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, Your problem is that in Django admin, you cannot see the data? If so, can you please send a picture of your BillingProfile model? ( not the manager) and ... since the billing_profile field in the address model is nullable, are you sure that they are not null in your rows ?

Comment: Please show your views for displaying and model as code not image

Comment: class BillingProfile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User ,null=True , blank=True , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email       = models.EmailField()
    active      =models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    time_stamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = BillingProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

Comment: sir this is my billing profile model

Comment: sir now i have edited every thing